# Fail to build flutter basic desktop plugin example

Tags: flutter, windows, build

I am a newbie in flutter development.
Created flutter plugin for android, ios and windows desktop with an example app using the android studio standard flutter project creation wizard.
Did not change anything.
The android project runs successfully on my device.
But windows desktop app fails to build :

[image]

```
[  +21 ms] Building Windows application... (completed in 
179.3s)
[        ] "flutter windows" took 184,471ms.
[   +3 ms] Build process failed.
[   +1 ms]
           #0      throwToolExit 
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
       #1      _runBuild 
(package:flutter_tools/src/windows/build_windows.dart:229:5)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #2      buildWindows 
(package:flutter_tools/src/windows/build_windows.dart:96:5)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #3      BuildWindowsCommand.runCommand 
(package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_windows.dart:56:5)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #4      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> 
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1323:27)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #5      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> 
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #6      CommandRunner.runCommand 
(package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous 
closure>

 (package: 
flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:339:9)
       
       
[ +218 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 213ms
[        ] Running 0 shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

The flutter doctor -v says:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 3.14.0-0.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows 
[Version 10.0.22621.2134], locale en-IL)
    • Flutter version 3.14.0-0.1.pre on channel beta at 
C:\Users\bsd040\Documents\FlutterDev\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 120d54d33a (10 days ago), 2023-08-17 
14:10:34 -0500
    • Engine revision f613b67824
    • Dart version 3.2.0 (build 3.2.0-42.1.beta)
    • DevTools version 2.26.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or 
higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 
version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\bsd040\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 
11.0.18+9-LTS-195)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program 
Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 
2022 17.3.5)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.3.32922.545
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0- 
b2043.56-9586694)

[!] Android Studio (version unknown)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
   https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    X Unable to determine Android Studio version.
    X android-studio-dir = C:\Program Files\Android\Android 
Studio\bin
    X Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.
    • Consider removing your android-studio-dir setting by running:
       flutter config --android-studio-dir=

[√] VS Code (version 1.80.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\bsd040\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft 
VS Code
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart- 
Code.flutter

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft 
Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2134]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 
116.0.5845.97
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 
115.0.1901.203

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Please help.

Tried the following:

1. to do flutter clean
2. enable windows desktop development in flutter by
   moving flutter to beta channel and by the command
   flutter config --enable-windows-desktop

However, it did not help.

Comment: What does `flutter doctor -v` say?

Comment: @Richard Heap Thanks a lot for a prompt answer . I've put the flutter doctor output inside the body of the original question

Comment: It seems that the problem , that the compiler can not find the C API file of the plugin:

 
 
 
**C:\MainData\Tetra\BluetoothFlutterPOC\flutter_bluetooth_serial_for_windows\example\windows\flutter\ephemeral\.plugin_symlinks\flut
ter_bluetooth_serial_for_windows\windows\flutter_bluetooth_serial_for_windows_plugin_c_api.cpp(1,10): fatal  error C1083: Cannot  
open include file: 'flutter_bluetooth_serial_for_windows_plugin_c_api.h': No such file or directory**


Although the file is found in the file system
What can be the problem?

Comment: Found the problem. May be will help to somebody.. It turned out that the path to the "non-found" file was too long. When I created new project with short folder name, everything worked successfully.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Of course the project name gets used 3 times in the path so you have a triple effect of a long project name. It would be good to add this as an answer, as comments are eventually lost.